# Sort Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in C#

Tags: c#, sorting, ms-word, document

I use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` to get words from Word file and then I populate it into a table layout panel. Unfortunately, the words displayed at the table layout panel are not following exact sequence as in the Word file.

How to fix this?

```
// Open a doc file.
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Document d ocument = application.Documents.Open(txtUploadedPathToken.Text);

// Loop through all words in the document.
int count = document.Words.Count;

for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{
    // Write the word.
    string text = document.Words[i].Text;
    //Console.WriteLine("Word {0} = {1}", i, text);
    tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = text, Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left, AutoSize = true}, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: If `document.Words` is truly an array, it'll be indexed from `0..(count - 1)` instead of the `1..count` you use here.

Comment: I tried to start from 0 and it gives me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your word document reading code seems OK. but you may need to change how you add items to panel. Since you add new items to same position (`0,0`) it may give incorrect order.

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range range in document.Words)
{
   string text = range.Text;
   tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = text, Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left, AutoSize = true});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposed solution but the result is still the same. Not following the sequence as in the Word file.

Comment: @user3248886, I think your problem is how you add controls to your panel, check my update, since you giving `0,0` position for each control it may give incorrect order

Comment: Yes, sir. It is now displaying according to the sequence after i remove 0,0. Thanks a lot.